# How to print the pdf file from wireless printer?

Tags: android

I want to print the pdf file from wireless printer. Is there any API available for printing?
Please suggest me how can I do this.

Thanks
Monali

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no API built into Android for wireless printing. You will need to contact the manufacturer of the wireless printer in question to see what protocols they support, then see if there is a third-party library for such a protocol.